# Overflow and Comments

Tags: comments

Go to this link and click where it says "2 comments" in the sub-title: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/01/17/lobortis-tellus-diam/

**When the link that brings the user to the comments is clicked it doesn't just scroll users down the page, it brings them to what APPEARS TO BE a separate page (even though it isn't a separate page). This is caused by the extreme margin/padding I am using in #sidebar and #post_content which I am using for equal height columns... http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight  Any fixes for this (while still using the equal height columns css)?**

THE CSS:

```
    #container {
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:35px auto
    }
    #sidebar {
        width: 410px;   
        display:block;
        padding-bottom: 32767px;
        margin-bottom: -32767px;
        float:right
    }
    #post_content {
        display:block;
        padding-right:25px;
        padding-bottom: 32767px;
        margin-bottom: -32767px;
        margin-right:25px;
        border-right:1px solid #EEE;
        float:left;
        width: 660px
    }
#commentlist {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%
}
```

THE LINK:

```
<a href="#commentlist"><?php comments_number( 'No comments', 'One comment', '% comments' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: that's the same page, there's something strange with your markup or css. if I remove `overflow:hidden` from `#container` the content appears again. just view page source, it's all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When links are broken into pages (via the settings in WordPress) and the link to bring a user to the comments is clicked it doesn't just scroll users down the page, it brings them to a separate page that is created.

Yes; this is standard WordPress functionality. Paginating comments results in *paginated posts*, with an appropriate query string parameter for the current comments page.

However, in this case, a separate page isn't being generated, because the post doesn't have enough comments for them to be paginated. Note that the only difference lies in the anchor ( `#comments` ) being appended to the URL. I concur with @Milo that this is a CSS/markup-related issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying to figure out how to fix this problem while still using the padding/margin for equal height columns as outlined in the link I posted.